# MVC: Extract RouteValues from Complex datatype

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I want to pass routeValues as a complex datatype into a HtmlHelper instead of using an anonymous type.

Eg.

```
@Html.Navigator("Title", Model.SearchCriteria)
```

and not

```
@Html.Navigator("Title", new {startDate=Model.StartDate, filter=Model.Filter, ...and so on})
```

With the latter I use:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Navigator(this HtmlHelper html, string title, object routeValues)

anchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", url.Action(action, routeValues));
```

to add the routeValues.

Can't work out how to do so for SearchCriteria.
Any advice, pointers..?

regards, Guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new RouteValuesDictionary based on an object. Assuming `Model.SearchCriteria` is typeof `SearchCriteria`

```
public static MvcHtmlString Navigator(this HtmlHelper html, string title, SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
{
  RouteValuesDictionary routeValues = new RouteValuesDictionary(searchCriteria);
```